# Internet Explorer 9 won't start

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have installed Internet Explorer 9. Now when I try to start it the application window flashes up briefly before closing again. What's wrong?

I have tried to uninstall IE9, then the problem persisted with IE8. I reinstalled IE9 and the problem is still there.

I have tried to use `inetcpl.cpl` to reset all settings and turn on software rendering, but it didn't help.

I can't find any error messages in the Event logs, and the crash doesn't give any kind of error message.

My system is Windows 7 Enterprise with SP1.

Comment: You can also try to do Microsoft's Fix It program. I've used that as a last resort in the past and fixed some weird issues I was having with IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps.

1. Scan your system for [malware](http://www.superantispyware.com/)
2. Update your graphics driver to the latest available, reboot and try IE9.
3. Run a [System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)
4. [Try this procedure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135) to see if a Service or Startup Program is interfering with IE9 launch

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I looked in `C:\program files\internet explorer` and there was an exe called `iecleanup.exe`. I ran that and voila! Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, the way I got around it was by going to internet options and deleting the browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Windows 7 SP1 64-bit machine with all updates installed. I reinstalled the graphics drivers and it didn't help.

Next I looked into the two Internet Explorer 9 folders (one in `C:\Program Files (x86)` and the other in `C:\Program Files`) and the 64-bit version of IE worked after running `IENRRECOVER.EXE`. The 32-bit version never worked.

I'll investigate further but what I did for the moment is patching the 64-bit IE9 to replace the 32-bit version of it. As soon I fix IE9 32-bit I'll repost with the fix.

Comment: Where did you find the IENRRECOVER.EXE?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar when I installed IE9 on Windows Vista. The browser window opened and after about a second I got a "Internet Explorer has stopped working..." dialog, and then the window was closed down.

After some investigation I found that it had to do with the new GPU acceleration features in IE9. My computer was too old to handle that. But there is a setting called "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering" in the Internet Options that, if un-ticked, solves the issue. Now IE starts as expected, without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen twice now, the first time with IE8 and now with IE9 - both times after system updates and restarts.

I think that the problem is that a restart rather than a reboot leaves a instance of IE running which blocks a new instance from displaying.

The solution is to go into Task Manager and kill the largest IE Process - all the others you tried to start will now populate the display.

Comment: My problem is not a one time problem after a restart. This happens consequently no matter if the computer has been powered off for days or just restarted.